# Rules to read bhagavth geeta and Ramayanam

Tags: belief, mahabharata, ramayana, bhagavad-gita

Can you please tell me the rules to follow while reading/Listening to the Bhagavat Gita and The Ramayanam? are they mandatory for every caste? because when I visited a Priest's home he didn't read in the evening for the reason of the sandhya vandhanam.

are there any rules, timings, Prerequisites, particular days and etc. to either read or listen to the great epics Viz. The MahaBharatha-(The Bhagavat Gita) and The Ramayanam?

- I already started reading The Ramayanam. I do not read it- while eating, before bath and Sandhya times(as I mentioned the priest didn't read so I am not reading it at Sandhya times).

Comment: I got the answer. Anyone can read our Purans, The Mahabhatha,The Ramayanam, at any clean and general place(like home,library.etc), but with calm mind and desire to understand. venue is secondary. Thank You!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramakrishna Paramahansa --Guru of Swami  Vivekananda , has said that there are no Rules or Timings regarding the study of Religious Texts . This is also the statement of Swami Vivekananda. 
 Since the study of Religious Texts are for Self Improvement ,every individual should find his/her own convenient place and time , when/where he/she study the texts Undisturbed and with Full Concentration. 
 Swami Vivekananda gives the example of Sun Light falling on a paper. It is bright enough to study the writings on the paper .But if  a Convex Lens is placed between the paper and Sunlight , so that the light is Focused on the paper ,the concentrated Sunlight  may burn the paper. 
 Concentrated study , similarly can Destroy one's Sins or the outer covering of Maya and enable one to know that Atma and Paramatma are One. " Aham Brahmasmi ". This is the objective of all spiritual texts--to teach that the Individual Soul is Potentially or Inherently Divine.